# How can I save file stored inside VARBINARY column into a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I stored my file into SQL Server in the form of a `VARBINARY` column in a table.
Here I'm trying to fetch that content and save it as a file into a folder:

```
List<FileData> newData = new List<FileData>();

var c = from n in db.FileTable
        where n.Id == 1
        select n;

foreach(var _somedata in c)
{
    var abc = new FileData
                {
                    _FileData = _somedata.FileData,
                    FileName = _somedata.FileName,
                };

    newData.Add(abc);
    string Img_name = abc.FileName;
    string folder_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images");

    if (!Directory.Exists(folder_path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder_path);
    }

    string imgPath = Path.Combine(folder_path, Img_name);
    ...
}
```

How can I store my file into that folder?

Comment: What is it the error that you are getting?

Comment: im not able to save my file in Image Folder

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes or use a FileStream

Comment: @Igor do u have any code please Share wirh

Comment: No but there is plenty out there in the documentation or [so]. Just google `how to write bytes to a file c#`.

Comment: @Igor Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a binary file, you could use the `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` method:

```
foreach(var _somedata in c)
{
    var abc = new FileData
                {
                    _FileData = _somedata.FileData,
                    FileName = _somedata.FileName,
                };

    string Img_name = abc.FileName;
    string folder_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images");

    if (!Directory.Exists(folder_path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder_path);
    }

    string imgPath = Path.Combine(folder_path, Img_name);

    // this call will write out all the bytes (content) of your file
    // to the file name you've specified   
    File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, abc._FileData);
}
```